# Cross Compiling ARM Kernel on 64bit machine

Tags: linux, kernel, cross-compilation, make, pi-1

I've been trying to cross compile a kernel for my Pi 1 on my 64bit Desktop, following this guide: https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/kernel/building.md

At this command (in the last section):

```
sudo make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabihf-
```

I get this error:

```
make: arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc: Command not found
```

Searching online, a proposed solution is to install `ia32-libs` if you're compiling from a 64bit machine. However, this package no longer exists, and as I understand it was used as a work around for 32bit support, so today the proper solution is to simply directly install the corresponding 32bit package you need for what you're doing. My question then is, what is the package I need? If I'm completely off and there's a different explanation to this problem, then ignore me, that's just what I gathered from my research online.

For additional information, I've tried this on Debian and have now reproduced the same results on OpenSUSE.

Comment: `ia32-libs` isn't that intel though?

Comment: I'm not sure, honestly. I have an AMD processor if that changes anything?

Comment: still wont help :p - does your PATH include `tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian-x64/bin`

Comment: Yes, as I said I've been following the guide I linked which has a step to add that to your PATH.

Comment: the issue is that your command is **incomplete** - in that howto, **triple** click on the command, you'll see `sudo make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabihf- INSTALL_MOD_PATH=mnt/ext4 modules_install` is one line, and you've only entered `sudo make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabihf-`

Comment: Oh wow, I feel like an idiot! I've just tired a clean compilation again with the full command, things are compiling now, although `make: arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc: Command not found` is still coming up. It does however look like all the files that should be there are there, so I'm going to assume this means it's worked. Thanks.

Comment: Don't feel bad. It's a poor layout on that web site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The page you linked https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/kernel/building.md

has a link near the bottom `VIEW/EDIT THIS PAGE ON GITHUB`

It sends you here https://github.com/raspberrypi/documentation/blob/master/linux/kernel/building.md

The commands on the github page are intact